# Why does my adjoin-set procedure in Scheme return an error?

Tags: set, syntax-error, scheme, lisp, anonymous-function

I'm trying to formulate a procedure that adjoins a number to a set of numbers that is ordered from least to greatest.  In this set, there are no duplicates, so I tried to solve this problem recursively by checking to see if the number to be adjoined is already equal to the `car` of the set and returning the set if true is returned, and if the number is larger than the `car` of the set if would perform the procedure again with the number and the `cdr` of the set.  If the set is null then it adjoins the number with the set because we know the number is not equal to any other number in the set.

Here is the code I wrote:

```lisp
(define (adjoin-set x set)
  (if (null? set)
        (cons x set)
        (let (x1 (car set))
          (cond ((= x x1) set)
                ((> x x1)(adjoin-set x (cdr set)))
                (else (cons x set))))))
```

I tested it on a set of odds: `(define odds '(1 3 5)) (adjoin-set 7 odds)` and [the interpreter](http://repl.it) returned the following: `Error: let: need a pair for bindings: got x1 []`.  Can anyone explain why this was returned and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your `let` expression is incorrect, it's missing a couple of `()`. It should be like this:

```
(define (adjoin-set x set)
  (if (null? set)
      (cons x set)
      (let ((x1 (car set)))
        (cond ((= x x1) set)
              ((> x x1) (adjoin-set x (cdr set)))
              (else (cons x set))))))
```

You can define multiple variable/value pairs inside a `let` declaration, the outermost parentheses are for grouping all of them together.

Comment: The syntax of `let` is the one part of scheme that I get wrong the most, I just figured that the extra parenthesis were extraneous.

Comment: @Jodast In Lisp no parentheses are ever redundant since they imply application everywhere where they do not have a syntax role. eg. `((something))` is the same as `something()()` in JavaScript. The syntax of special forms like `let` and `lambda` needs to be memorized and that leaves customer syntax introduced by macros. These cause confusion so unless they are to be used at least 10 times it's probably best to not make it in the first place.